# Iteration bound variable?

Tags: c#, language-agnostic, iteration

This is non-language-specific, but I'll use examples in `C#`. Often I face the problem in which I need to add a `parameter` to an `object` inside any given iteration of at least one of its parameters, and I have always to come up with a *lame* temporary `list` or `array` of some kind concomitant with the problem of keeping it properly correlated.

So, please bear with me on the examples below:

- Is there an easier and better way to do this in C sharp?

  ```
  List<String> storeStr;

  void AssignStringListWithNewUniqueStr (List<String> aList) {
      foreach (String str in aList) {
          storeStr.add(str);
          str = AProcedureToGenerateNewUniqueStr();
      }
  }

  void PrintStringListWithNewUniqueStr (List<String> aList) {
      int i = 0;
      foreach (String str in aList) {
          print(str + storeStr[i]);
          i++;
      }
  }
  ```

Notice the *correlation* above is guaranteed only because I'm iterating through an unchanged `aList`. When asking about a "easier and better way" I mean it should also make sure the `storeStr` would always be *correlated* with its equivalent on `aList` while keeping it as short and simple as possible. The `List` could also have been any kind of `array` or `object`.

---

- Is there any language in which *something* like this is possible? It must give same results than above.

  ```
  IterationBound<String> storeStr;

  void AssignStringListWithNewUniqueStr (List<String> aList) {
      foreach (String str in aList) {
          storeStr = str;
          str = AProcedureToGenerateNewUniqueStr();
      }
  }

  void PrintStringListWithNewUniqueStr (List<String> aList) {
      foreach (String str in aList) {
          print(str + storeStr);
      }
  }
  ```

In this case, the fictitious "`IterationBound`" kind would guarantee the *correlation* between the list and the new parameter (in a way, just like Garbage Collectors guarantee allocs). It would somehow notice it was created inside an iteration and associate itself with that specific index (no matter if the syntax there would be uglier, of course). Then, when its called back again in another iteration and it was already created or stored in that specific index, it would retrieve this specific value of that iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply project your enumerable into a new form?

```
var combination = aList
      .Select(x => new { Initial = x, Addition = AProcedureToGenerateNewUniqueStr() })
      .ToList()
      .ForEach(x =>
           { 
               print(x.Initial + x.Addition);
           });
```

This way you keep each element associated with the new data.

Comment: Actually... Now I found couple of issues with this... First the practical one: I couldn't figure out a way to declare `combination` to be used outside the scope of a method (as pointed in the newly edited question). As for the "feeling good" issue: it seems like an overkill: something that may add restrictions to its usage. I haven't tested it yet, but now I wonder if it would work in my usage case: unity3d on ios.

Comment: If you need to access it outside a method, you would need to make a strongly typed object to use instead of an anonymous object, for example `Tuple<int, int>` etc. Then combination is an `IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>>` which you can specify on the return type.

Answer (score 2):

```
aList.ForEach(x => print(x + AProcedureToGeneratorNewUniqueString()));
```

Comment: How did I miss the point? The chosen answer has the same functionality of my solution.

Comment: Yes, sure! And sorry for taking weekend off. First, please check if my *edit* on the question helps clarifying it for you. Then, the point is being able to store the "*x*" for later retrieval, which simply can't happen this way you pointed. You're not storing it or retrieving it in any way.